# i'm tryng tu build this ecm model Δy_t=α_02+α_2^* e ̂_(t-1)+v_2t from a rolling ols model that i've already estimated

Tags: python-3.x

```
window_size = 72
shift_step = 1
results = []

for i in range(0, len(T1) - window_size + 1, shift_step):
    T1_window = T1[i:i + window_size]
    EFFR_window = EFFR[i:i + window_size]
    model_ols = sm.OLS(T1_window, sm.add_constant(EFFR_window)).fit()
    resid1r = model_ols.resid

    result = adfuller(resid1r)
    p_value = result[1]
    results.append(p_value)

    df1r = pd.DataFrame(results)
    df1r.to_excel('pvalues1r2.xlsx', index=False)   


    ecm_term1 = resid1r.iloc[i:i + window_size].shift(1)
    ecm_x = sm.add_constant(EFFR.diff().iloc[i:i + window_size])
    ecm_y = T1.diff().iloc[i:i + window_size]
    ecm_x['error_correction'] = ecm_term1

    ecm_model = sm.OLS(ecm_y[1:], ecm_x[1:]).fit()

    p_values_error_correction.append(ecm_model.pvalues['error_correction'])

    df_results = pd.DataFrame({'P-value_error_correction': p_values_error_correction})
    df_results.to_excel('p_values_error_correction1f.xlsx', index=False)
```

how can i adjust my code. i want create an ecm model for each window of 72 observation taking residuals of the previous regression, lagged of 1, as correction term. Thanks for the help

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.